# Code generator in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, code-generation, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

Anybody who knows how to translate this pseudocode into MIPS assembly? Seed is a global variable

```
FUNCTION codgen(): UNSIGNED INTEGER;
LOCAL SIGNED INTERGER n;
LOCAL UNSIGNED INTEGER x,y;
BEGIN
n:= [right-justify the five bits "seed"<24:20>, and zero-extend];
WHILE (n >= 0) LOOP
x := [shift "seed" left-logical by 3 bits];
y := [divide "seed" (unsigned) by the constant 16];
seed:= x-y; [ignore overflow condition]
n := n-1;
ENDLOOP
RETURN( seed XOR 0x0176f7df);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I believe will work:

```
# codgen -- generate code or random number
#
#@+
# FUNCTION codgen(): UNSIGNED INTEGER;
# LOCAL SIGNED INTEGER n;
# LOCAL UNSIGNED INTEGER x,y;
# BEGIN
#   n := [right-justify the five bits "seed"<24:20>, and zero-extend];
#   WHILE (n >= 0) LOOP
#     x := [shift "seed" left-logical by 3 bits];
#     y := [divide "seed" (unsigned) by the constant 16];
#     seed := x-y; [ignore overflow condition]
#     n := n-1;
#   ENDLOOP
#   RETURN (seed XOR 0x0176f7df);
# END;
#@-
#
# arguments:
#   s0 -- seed
#
# NOTE:
#   under mips, the phrase "seed is a global variable" allows it to be in a
#   register. if it had to be a global "in memory" (e.g.):
#     seed: .word 0
#   just add (at start):
#     lw $s0,seed
#   and (at end):
#     sw $s0,seed
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- n
#   t1 -- x
#   t2 -- y
codgen:
    srl     $t0,$s0,20              # get seed bits 24-20 to lower 5 bits
    andi    $t0,$t0,0x1F            # isolate them
    j       codgen_start            # start loop

codgen_loop:
    sll     $t1,$s0,3               # x = seed << 3
    srl     $t2,$s0,4               # y = (unsigned) seed / 16 (aka seed >> 4)
    subu    $s0,$t1,$t2             # seed = x - y

    subi    $t0,$t0,1               # n -= 1
codgen_start:
    bgez    $t0,codgen_loop         # n >= 0? if yes, loop

    xori    $v0,$s0,0x0176F7DF      # ret = seed ^ 0x0176F7DF
    jr      $ra                     # return
```

The above is *just* desk checked. I did *not* actually run it and I did *not* write a C version first to provide a diagnostic/reference implementation because ...

No offense, but, the pseudo-code being of some ["ancient" :-)] language origin such as Algol, Pascal, Ada, VHDL(?), or [modern] Fortran, I had some difficulty in figuring out the algorithm/intent.

The translation to C would have been just as error prone as the direct translation to asm.